# Android textview color change without any reason

Tags: android, colors, textview

Today I used my app on a device with android 4.1 and I found a really annoying bug.

Without any reason the textviewschanged their color every time Irefreshed the screen(e.g.: resume a fragment).

[image]

In this screen all texts are black but here they are all white.
Other times some are black, other are white.

This is a general textview declaration in my app.

```
<TextView           
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/overview"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

This is the first time that I've seen this bug on my app.

EDIT 1:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Overview();                    
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_1, fragment, "root").commit();
```

Comment: Can you post how you are adding the `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the file "strings.xml" in "values" --> "res" folder:

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

and add the next line to your TextView definition:

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
```

Comment: What I've thought...the problem is only that i have more than 400 textview in my app  =(  Thanks! I'll try this solution

Comment: Oh, so maybe there's an option to change it all together?... anyway, goodluck! Let me know if it's working

Comment: Yes, fortunately I' ve remembered that I can use styles! Tomorrow I'll try this on the device of a friend of mine and I'll mark your answer as correct